# magento product list.phtml

Tags: list, magento, product, php

If I click on a product from my product overview on the left side, the shop does not load with the list.phtml. As soon as I swap view to grid or list, it swaps to the list.phtml file and everything is fine. But as I said, if I click on the products on the sidebar, it doesnt work (it's not even affected by list.phtml at all). I removed all the code inside it and it still showed (a bit different, that's why I want to change it) the products, but as soon as I swapped mode, everything disappeared -- as it should. Do you know where I can change that?
Thank you.

Comment: Provide some screenshots so that other can clearly understand what you are up to.

Comment: best would be you try it out yourself: www.ihnkenrollen.de      if you click on a product category on the left sidebar and change to "grid" everything is fine, but now klick on the same product category again. it will change, because its not affected by list.phtml

Comment: Are you trying to show the list view on category click although grid mode was choosen previously? Or i am not getting you,what is happening now is the default flow.

Comment: if i click on the product category it will have list mode by default, if i change it to grid mode, everything is fine (it has list.phtml attached). now if i click on the product category again (of course its still grid view) it will change the layout because its not using the list.phtml anymore or another one. how can i figure out which file it uses?

Comment: I have added answer to it because i couldn't explain it in comment due to its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should use list.phtml file. In that file it is defined for both list mode and grid mode.

```
 <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
```

And

```
<?php else: ?>
<?php // Grid Mode ?>
<?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
```

You can see something like above code in your **list.phtml** file,one is for list mode and another for grid mode. This is the default case unless you haven't changed the layout or template code.

If you want to know the file location than you can always enable template path hint. If you don't know how to do that you can [follow this](https://support.sweettoothrewards.com/entries/21255937-How-do-I-turn-on-template-path-hints-).

After knowing from which file it is rendering you can fix it.

Hope this will help.

Comment: if i remove the list.phtml file, it still shows if i click on the product category, it just doesnt show something when i change the view, so there must be 2 "list.phtml" files right?

Comment: may be. enable the template path hint to exactly determine which file it is using.

Comment: i did that, thanks for the tip. i think i should be able to solve it now

Comment: ok i know which phtml file it uses now, but where can i change it that it uses the normal one? i think its in a xml file but i dont know where?

Comment: Actually i cannot tell this with looking the codes, but if you know the phtml file which it uses than search with that name in the xml files you may get the xml file.It should be in catalog.xml file.Have a look in that file in your theme.